# set variable to element from other site (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I'm not the best at explaining things but here I go,
On a different site, I have 10 elements that i want to get and assign to variables
this is how they are

element 1:

```html
<div class="username_header dynamic_fontsize" style="font-size: 48px; top: 0px;">
<span class="username">[element 1]</span>
<span class="user_online_msg">stuff</span>
</div>
```

elements 2-10

```html
<div class="forum_profile_right_block">
   <table border="0" width="97%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc2</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 2]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc34</div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 3]</td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 4]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc5</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 5]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc6</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 6]
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc7</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 7]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc8</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 8]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc9</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
               <div style="display:inline-block;">[element 9]</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 1px;"><img src="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" class="flag us"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="font-color:black; font-size:1em">abc10</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">[element 10]
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <br>
</div>
```

Comment: and? What is the question/problem? Where is any php code?

Comment: It's also not clear (to me) what you are trying to achieve. Is the shown html on the "other site"?

Comment: In it's current form, this "question" is not a question. Please edit this to be more clear as to your inquiry.

Comment: My guess: You wanna grab data from another site. correct?

Comment: @Poootaatoooo No, there's absolutely no need to collaborate. - I'm gone.

Comment: Google "web scraping in php"